# Service для отправки уведомлений в фоне

Tags: android, android-service, android-notification

Есть задача, состоящая в том, чтобы при обновлении базы на `Firebase`, выводились уведомления об конкретных изменениях даже в том случае, если приложение вообще не запущено (ну или хотя бы работает в фоне). В связи с этим стал искать, как это можно реализовать. Нашел, что это можно сделать при помощи `Service`. Когда начал делать первые наработки, нашел еще `IntentService`. Стал смотреть, в чем их отличия, но нашел лишь то, что он является подклассом `Service` для "выполнения тяжелых задач". При дальнейшем поиске стали попадаться слова, что `Service'ы` вообще не предназначены для долгих задач.

С самими `Event'ами` при обновлении `Firebase` проблем нет, но хотелось бы все-таки узнать, как будет правильнее поступить в данной ситуации, и как делают реализуют такие задачи правильно. Из моих идей есть только: сделать `IntentService` и в метод `onHandleIntent` записать `Listener` на обновление `Firebase`, при выполнении которого будет отправляться уведомления. Но я не уверен, что будет правильно делать это таким способом.

Собственно, вопрос в том, можно ли называть правильной мою идею и, если нет, то как это делается правильно?

Comment: Разница между `Service` и `IntentService` в асинхронности - первое работает в `UI` потоке, второй работает в отдельном потоке. И как раз таки сервисы нужны для того, чтобы помещать туда сложные и долгие задачи. Сервис - аналог службы в винде. А службы выполняют все действия невидимо для пользователя и постоянно.

Comment: Хорошая идея! И мне кажется, что она в данном варианте - это лучший способ.Если вы уже реализовали данным способом - расскажите, как Firebase работает с фоновой службой? Если вы повесили addValueEventListener, то он не хранит старое значение(ну то, что изменилось), и его приходится записывать куда-нибудь, чтобы вести сравнение постоянно в службе.

Comment: Можно воспользоваться и обычным сервисом, но свои действия оборачивай в отдельный Thread

Comment: Есть уже какое-то решение? Тоже эта тема интересует.

Answer (score 1):

1)создайте intentservise 
2)добавте broadcastreceiver

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
Context mContext;
private final String BOOT_ACTION = "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    mContext = context;
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(BOOT_ACTION)) {

        //Запускаем сервис после полного выключения телефона
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
}



<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

```
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
```

3)реализуйте в сервисе получение данных из firebase

```
import 
java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyIntentService extends 
IntentService {

private final String TAG = "IntentServiceLogs";

public MyIntentService() {
    super("myname");
}

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

DatabaseReference databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("39714936");

String input = "G";

DatabaseReference cities = databaseRef.child("cities");
Query citiesQuery = cities.orderByKey().startAt(input).endAt(input + "\uf8ff");
citiesQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String> cities = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            cities.add(postSnapshot.getValue().toString());
        }
        System.out.println(cities);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
}
}
```